# What is difference between "size" and "storageSize" displayed by Mongo stats() function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is difference between "size" and "storageSize" displayed by Mongo `stats()` function? Which one shows the actual size on disk for a particular collection? Refer sample data returned by command

```
db.getCollection('temp_collection').stats()


{"ns" : "DB1.temp_collection",
    "count" : 1035219,
    "size" : 1186,
    "avgObjSize" : 1202,
    "storageSize" : 177,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : 
}
```

Comment: `1202*1035219/(1024^2) == 1186.6886...` So that's what `size` means.

Comment: @Bakuriu - this is not part of the question :-)

Answer (score 19):

in simple words:

- `size` refers for logical allocation (this is seen by database engine)
- `storageSize` refers for physical file space allocation

As WT (WiredTiger) is  used, with enabled data compression, then physical allocation is smaller because of compression

[db.collection.storageSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.storageSize/)

[db.collection.stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/)