# MongoDB: maximum number of documents in a capped collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a capped collection and I defined max size to be `512000000` (512MB)

stats() says (After 1 insert): `size:55, storageSize:16384`.

Assuming that all documents are the same size, how many documents can I store?

Is it `512000000 / 55` or `512000000 / 16384`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between "size" and "storageSize" displayed by Mongo stats() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345630/what-is-difference-between-size-and-storagesize-displayed-by-mongo-stats-f)

Comment: TBH, no, It's still not obvious to me. Also, `stats()` shows for me that `storageSize > size`, even though I have WiredTiger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a capped collection, it's `maxSize / avgObjSize`. If your documents are about the same size, then it's practically `maxSize / size`.

You can verify this using a smaller more manageable number:

```
// create a capped collection with maxSize of 1024
> db.createCollection('test', {capped: true, size: 1024})

// insert one document to get an initial size
> db.test.insert({a:0})
> db.test.stats().size
33

// with similar documents, the collection should contain 1024/33 ~= 31 documents
// so let's insert 100 to make sure it's full
> for(i=1; i<100; i++) { db.test.insert({a:i}) }

> db.test.stats()
{
    "ns" : "test.test",
    "size" : 1023,
    "count" : 31,
    "avgObjSize" : 33,
    "storageSize" : 36864,
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : -1,
    "maxSize" : 1024,
....
```

so from the experiment above, `count` is 31 as expected, even though we inserted 100 documents.

Using your numbers, the max number of documents in your capped collection would be 512000000 / 55 ~= 9,309,090 documents.